# C# XmlSerializer can't serialize after casting member to System.Object

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

A simple struct:

```
public struct TestA
{
    public object value;
}
```

Create it and serialize it:

```
List<string> value = new List<string>();
value.Add("a1");
TestA a = new TestA();
a.value = value;

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(a.GetType());
xml.Serialize(stream, a);
```

Can't be serialized, InvalidOperationException: The type of the argument object 'System.Collections.Generic.List' is not primitive.

If I change `"public object value;"` to `"public List<string> value;"`, it can be serialized.

I want to use this `object value` to store value with different types, so I make the type as `object`.
Such as:

```
a.value = new List<int>();
a.value = 3;
a.value = "a string";
```

Comment: The only way that I can think of is to use custom xml serialization: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do the job.

```
[Serializable]
public class TestA : IXmlSerializable
{
    public object value;

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return (null);
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        value = reader.ReadContentAsObject();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both code4life and Soham, I haven't tested your idea, because I found a very simple way.
Give XmlSerializer the second paramter, give it the exact type of the `object value`.

```
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(a.GetType(), new Type[] { typeof(List<string>) });
```